# Object Required: VBA Excel, Range selection

Tags: vba, excel, object, error-code

So I am getting an error in this line of code in this particular selection structure I am trying to formulate. I am trying to dynamically select a range based off of the selection of Demand and a user entry that gets read into UB, However I keep getting the object required error and am sure what is wrong (I know my code is a bit redundant at a certain part, I was getting an another error code about range and left some of the redundancies for now!)

```
   Dim y As Integer
   UB = TextBox1.Text
   y = UB + 4
   srange = "C" & 4 & ":" & "J" & y

   If ComboBox2.Text = "Demand" Then
    Worksheets("SensitivityDemand").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Welcome").Visible = False
    Worksheets("SensitivityDemand").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("SensitivityDemand").Select

    With ActiveSheets
        .Range("srange").Select          'Object required here 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Table RowInput:=Range("B3"), ColumnInput:=Range("B4")
```

Comment: Remove the quotes

Comment: I've tried to remove the quotes around srange, and still get the same error message.

Comment: @Ancheda.B.Anthony Can you print the value of `srange` with `Debug.Print` and give the result? What is supposed to be in `TextBox1`? I think your error come from invalid data in `srange` which make the `Range("srange")` false.

Comment: ActiveSheets should be ActiveSheet.  singular

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below code and let me know if there is any thing missing.

```
Dim y As Integer
UB = TextBox1.Text
y = UB + 4
srange = "C" & 4 & ":" & "J" & y

If ComboBox2.Text = "Demand" Then
Worksheets("SensitivityDemand").Visible = True
Worksheets("Welcome").Visible = False
Worksheets("SensitivityDemand").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
'Sheets("SensitivityDemand").Select


    ActiveSheet.Range(srange).Select          'Object required here 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Table RowInput:=Range("B3"), ColumnInput:=Range("B4")
```

Do no use the ActiveSheets
Also `srange` do not put those in double qoutes as it has some values passed to it. So if you put `srange` in double qoutes it will treat as a string not a value.